# Get the sum of quantities grouped by an Id that is not in the current table

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three models that look something like this:

```js
const Reagent = sequelize.define('reagent', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ...
  })
  const Box = sequelize.define('box', {
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ...
  })

  const BoxActivity = sequelize.define('boxActivity', {
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.Date,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  })
Reagent.hasMany(Box);
Box.belongsTo(Reagent);
BoxActivity.belongsTo(Box);
Box.hasMany(BoxActivity);
```

I want to get the reagent list with the sum of the quantity (`quantity` from BoxActivity) model but I don't know how to achieve this.
I have written this:

```js
await BoxActivity.findAll({
      attributes: ['boxId', [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('quantity')), 'totalQuantity']],
      group: ['boxId'], // I need it grouped by reagent not box.
      where: {
        quantity: {
          [Op.gt]: 0
        }
      }
    })
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define foreign key references in your schema, afterward in your query you can include them like this

```
modelA.findAll({
    include:[
        {model:modelB,attributes:[]},
        {model:modelC,attributes:[]}
    ],
    attributes:[
        //here you can access and manipulate modelB and modelC's columns 
        // like this sequelize.col('"modelB"."id"') and even use them in 
        //group by or order by
    ]

})
```